# SSMA Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration

I have the following query in Access but it does not convert to SQL when using SSMA.  The converter gives the following errors all related to the IIf statements

```
*   SSMA error messages:
   *   A2SS0061: The identifier 'IIf(BOOLEAN, VARCHAR, UNKNOWN)' was not converted.
   *   A2SS0061: The identifier 'IIf(BOOLEAN, VARCHAR, UNKNOWN)' was not converted.
   *   A2SS0061: The identifier 'IIf(BOOLEAN, VARCHAR, UNKNOWN)' was not converted.
   *   A2SS0061: The identifier 'IIf(BOOLEAN, VARCHAR, VARCHAR)' was not converted.
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

```
    SELECT tblkpitracking.kpitrackingday,
       tblkpitracking.kpitrackingweek,
       tblkpitracking.kpitrackingmonth,
       tblkpitracking.kpitrackingvalue,
       tblworkstream.workstreamshorthand,
       tblworkstream.workstream,
       tblworkstreamkpi.kpiid,
       tblkpitracking.workstreamkpiid,
       Iif([unit] = '--', '', [unit]) &
       Iif([bytimeperiod] = '--', '', [bytimeperiod])
       & Iif([byunit] = '--', '', [byunit]) &
       Iif([unit] = '--'
           AND [bytimeperiod] = '--'
           AND [byunit] = '--', 'TBD', '') AS
       CleanKPI,
       [workstreamshorthand] & ': ' & [cleankpi]
       AS WorkStreamShortKPIClean,
       [workstream] & ': ' & [cleankpi]
       AS WorkStreamKPIClean,
       tblworkstreamkpi.kpiclarification,
       tblworkstreamkpi.kpibaselinevalue,
       tblworkstreamkpi.kpitargetvalue
FROM   tblworkstream
       INNER JOIN ((tblunits
                    INNER JOIN ((tblbyunits
                                 INNER JOIN (tblbytimeperiod
                                             INNER JOIN tblkpi
                                                     ON
                                             tblbytimeperiod.bytimeperiodid
                                             =
                                             tblkpi.bytimeperiodid)
                                         ON tblbyunits.byunitsid =
                                            tblkpi.byunitsid)
                                INNER JOIN tblworkstreamkpi
                                        ON tblkpi.kpiid =
                               tblworkstreamkpi.kpiid)
                            ON tblunits.unitsid = tblkpi.unitsid)
                   INNER JOIN tblkpitracking
                           ON tblworkstreamkpi.workstreamkpiid =
                              tblkpitracking.workstreamkpiid)
               ON tblworkstream.workstreamid = tblworkstreamkpi.workstreamid;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are  you using?

Comment: I use SQL server 2014 but this problem is related to SSMA 6.0 not SQL server.  

SSMA is a stand-alone product that has been around and that has replaced the upsize database function available in versions of Access < 2013.  Access 2013 does not have an upsize function, one has to use SSMA. Apparently the upsize wizard created more problems than it solved.

In essence, SSMA 6.0 does not want to translate IIF statement into CASE statements unless I am overlooking something.  

However the developers of SSMA spent time on calculating how much time the user would need  to do a manual translation!